# Cannot start AptanaStudio3 OS X 10.7 Lion

Tags: macos

When I start AptanaStudio3 I get the following error:

Alert

The AptanaStudio3 executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library.

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to reinstall java before apatana would start.